# how do I allow the user to write their own implementation of a predefined method like accept() in FilenameFilter

Tags: java, design-patterns, itext

`FilenameFilter` has an [accept](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) method that I can implement to tell system how I want to filter files. I want to implement something this similar. Here is my scenario:

I am writing a generic API that run on top of [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) that adding [Barcode](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode.html) to pdf documents. I have a generic custom Barcode.

```
public class MyCustomBarcode{

/**
 * This variable holds the type of barcode
 * com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode
 */
private Barcode barcode;

/**
 * The X position of the barcode. (0, 0) is at the bottom left
 */
private float x;

/**
 * The Y position of the barcode. (0, 0) is at the bottom left
 */
private float y;

/**
 * 
 */
private int rotation;

...
}
```

So when the user use this API, they just need pass in a `List<MyCustomBarcode>` to a method from my API, then API will insert barcode on to every pdf page. The problem is every barcode has different [code](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode.html#setCode%28java.lang.String%29) format. For example, BarcodeInter25 might use code like `000001, 000002 ...` where Barcode39 might use something else. So I want to allow the user to write their own implementation of how to generate the value of the barcode. Something like this

```
MyCustomBarcode barcode = new MyCustomBarcode(x, y, z){
    public String getSeqNum(int i){
       //The user own implementation of how they want integer i to look like.
       //E.g if i==1, I might return 000001
    }
);
```

**And since I allow user to have multiples type of barcode, I want to allow them to write their own implementation for every barcode that they have.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent class, make the method `abstract`, and then have each subclass provide their own concrete implementation.

---

### Example

#### Parent class

```
public abstract class Barcode{
    .
    .
    .
    public abstract String getSeqNum(int i);
}
```

#### Subclass

```
public final class FooBarcode extends Barcode{
    .
    .
    .
    public final String getSeqNum(int i){
        // provide own implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question with a bit more details. Can you give me a bit more information. Maybe some pseudo code, or links or something that I can see a bit clearer?

Comment: @HarryPham, I included an example.